# Order by not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Order by is not working for angularjs

```
<div class="friendprofile" ng-repeat="like in likePages| filter:likePages.pagename|orderBy:'likePages.pagename'">
    <img ng-src="{{like.pageimg}}">
    <span><a ng-href="#">{{like.pagename}}</a> </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's enough if you use

```
orderBy:'pagename'
```

Predicate is a property of an iterator. In your case it would be ordered by `like['pagename']`

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/2bXWUadA2Lb8zhAXnnlp?p=preview

> A predicate to be used by the comparator to determine the order of
>   elements.
>
> Can be one of:
>
> **function**: Getter function. The result of this function will be sorted
>   using the <, =, > operator.
>
> **string**: An Angular expression which
>   evaluates to an object to order by, such as 'name' to sort by a
>   property called 'name'. Optionally prefixed with + or - to control
>   ascending or descending sort order (for example, +name or -name).
>
> **Array**: An array of function or string predicates. The first predicate
>   in the array is used for sorting, but when two items are equivalent,
>   the next predicate is used.

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy